How to disable window grouping in Ubuntu 24.04
Does anyone know how to disable window grouping in Ubuntu 24.04? I find the window grouping very stressful and wish it would give people the option not to have it.
Looking through the forum it seems that people have talked about how to disable the window grouping in older threads that related to older versions of Ubuntu but it seems that Ubuntu 24.04 does not allow this anymore? Looking through old posts it seems that many people have wanted the option of ungrouping windows and that this functionality was brought in, in response, but sadly now it seems to have been taken away?
Previous threads talked of right clicking on an empty space on the panel and then clicking on Configure Panel, which would then allow you to untick window grouping. I already tried Settings>Ubuntu Desktop>Enhanced Tiling Uncheck Tile Groups but unfortunately that doesn't work, it doesn't change anything and multiple windows of the same program still group together.
I note that Linux Mint allows you to ungroup windows but maybe because it's based on a much older kernel before functionality was taken away perhaps? Some very old threads on here talked of right clicking on empty space on the panel (when I do this it does nothing) and then go into manage widgets, then go into task manager, go into settings and disable window grouping but this option doesn't seem to exist anymore (apart from the enhanced tiling under settings which unfortunately doesn't do anything). Unless there is a way to fix this? Or something I am missing?
Many thanks for any help with this

Thanks Kos you make a good point, I've broken it down and tried to make my question clearer

Thanks, so here's the deal, I'm pretty sure disabling the enhanced window tiling extension used to apply immediately, however I tried doing that again and in fact it doesn't seem to work. However it worked immediately after I logged out / logged back into GNOME, can you try and disable it again, logging out before testing whether it worked or not?

Also if that alone doesn't work: gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com; dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/edge-tiling true + log out / log in should bring everything back to a default with the extension disabled and Mutter's tiling enabled, which should be basically what you want

Thanks a lot Kos and sorry for my delayed response, I was trying to research how to do this, I'm not technical. I first tried logging out of my computer but that didn't work. I then tried putting that script you gave into the command line but after I entered "disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com" it said "disable: command not found". So I did some googling and found that there is a GNOME Extension Manager app however when I open that app it says that the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant extension is already turned off (presumably because I had already turned Enhanced tiling off) Yet the tiling persists!

Judging from the message I think you left out the gnome-extension part from the command, try and run it again, make sure you copy the complete command

Thank you Kos, I tried copying the complete command and got this error: ~$ ^[[200~gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com; dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/edge-tiling true~
gnome-extensions: command not found
error: 4:expected end of input
Usage:
dconf write KEY VALUE
Write a new value to a key
Arguments:
KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)

You have weird characters in your command, that ^[[200~ shouldn't be there. Make sure to copy the command precisely with CTRL + C and to paste it with CTRL + Shift + C in the terminal

Thanks again Kos. I actually copied the command you gave precisely but somehow it inserted weird characters at the beginning that I didn't put there. It happened again when I copied what you gave, and it wouldn't let me delete them so I typed it manually exactly as you gave it. I then got another error message but I don't want to waste your time as I'm not technical and I think Ubuntu is geared to more technical people. I will ask someone to help me and let you know how I go

This was the error message: gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com; dconf write / org/gnome/mutter/edge-tiling true
error: dconf key must not end with a slash
Usage:
dconf write KEY VALUE
Write a new value to a key
Arguments:
KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)

No problem, the ^[[200~ is inserted if you first attempt to paste using CTRL + V and then actually paste using CTRL + Shift + V (which is the right way), so to avoid the issue you should try and get it right the first time; on the error: it tested the command and it works for me. It should work for you as well, please make sure there's no trailing slash after edge-tiling in the command before running it. Try and copy-paste it again paying attention to these two things

Thanks for explaining that Kos. I asked someone who is technical (using Ubuntu since the early days) & he also copied your command precisely, double checking & ensuring there was no trailing slash.  And then I logged out and in again but it's still tiling windows. I tried the command again several times myself checking it was precisely the same as what you gave, also trying to turn tiling back on in the settings beforehand to see if that made any difference but for some reason it doesn't get rid of the tiling for me.

I don't want to take any more of your time. Hopefully the next version will fix the issue of turning off enhanced tiling in the settings not actually turning off the tiling (without the need for your command which for some reason didn't work for me). Thanks so much for your help

You're welcome - anyways that's weird, and I don't know how to explain the fact that it doesn't work for you - I've tried this again (also using the opposite version, which enables the extension and turns off mutter's tiling) - and they both work. Perhaps you should try and update your system and this is simply a matter of something outdated. Good luck!

Thanks Kos, I have the latest version 24.04 and just applied the latest update and tried your solution again exactly but after logging back in it is still grouping the windows despite it being switched off in the settings. Hopefully the bug will be fixed automatically in version 24.05 and other future versions - but meanwhile perhaps this thread will help people your solution works for. Thanks again!

I do not use GNOME so this is only a guess, but I believe Ubuntu's version of GNOME uses an extension to do this. Perhaps remove that extension?

It is called the Ubuntu GNOME Tiling Assistant. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-tiling-assistant

Thanks a lot Liam. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to let you remove the Tiling Assistant extension but I have turned it off but that doesn't stop it from tiling :(

Reading your other comments, I am not sure you are ready to deal with GNOME let alone customising it. I suggest you switch to Linux Mint instead, probably with Cinnamon. It is easier and friendlier.

Thanks for your suggestion Liam and I agree. For that reason I'd tried Linux Mint with Cinnamon first but it gave me a problem where my mouse and keyboard would stop working intermittently and I had to switch to Ubuntu in order to have a stable system. From my research it seemed this had been an issue for some people with older kernels and since Linux Mint has a very dated kernel I imagine that's why I was having the problem with Mint but not when I switched to Ubuntu. Nevertheless Linux Mint did allow me to turn off the tiling because it was based on an old kernel that enabled that for me!

Mint 22 is based on Ubuntu 24.04 so it is a lot more modern now. The Mint project has also started tracking Ubuntu HWE kernels, which means not only is it more modern but it will stay more current in future. It was always possible to install HWE kernels as well, just like on Ubuntu itself: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Thanks for letting me know Liam, that's wonderful news! In that case I will go back to Mint again in future. Thanks for your help!
